# How to run prolog text file using Mac Terminal?

Tags: swi-prolog

I can't run the file from text edit. I keep getting errors. What am prompts am I missing in order to run prolog fully?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  For the best experience when asking questions you should consider a minimum viable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!  Please include what you've tried and the results.